# C++ get parameters before a for loop or not

Tags: c++, performance, loops, sdl-2

What is the best practice in this case:

Should I get variables before running a for loop like this:

```
void Map::render(int layer, Camera* pCam)
{
    int texture_index(m_tilesets[layer]->getTextureIndex());

    int tile_width(m_size_of_a_tile.getX());
    int tile_height(m_size_of_a_tile.getY());

    int camera_x(pCam->getPosition().getX());
    int camera_y(pCam->getPosition().getY());

    int first_tile_x(pCam->getDrawableArea().getX());
    int first_tile_y(pCam->getDrawableArea().getY());

    int map_max_x( (640 / 16) + first_tile_x );
    int map_max_y( (360 / 16) + first_tile_y );

    if (map_max_x > 48) { map_max_x = 48; }
    if (map_max_y > 28) { map_max_x = 28; }

    Tile* t(nullptr);

    for (int y(first_tile_y); y < map_max_y; ++y) {
        for (int x(first_tile_x); x < map_max_x; ++x) {

            // move map relative to camera
            m_dst_rect.x = (x * tile_width) + camera_x;
            m_dst_rect.y = (y * tile_height) + camera_y;

            t = getTile(layer, x, y);
            if (t) {
                pTextureManager->draw(texture_index, getTile(layer, x, y)->src, m_dst_rect);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or is it better to get it directly in the loop like this (in this case the code is shorter but less readable):

```
void Map::render(int layer, Camera* pCam)
{
    int first_tile_x(pCam->getDrawableArea().getX());
    int first_tile_y(pCam->getDrawableArea().getY());

    for (int y(first_tile_y); y < (640 / 16) + first_tile_x; ++y) {
        for (int x(first_tile_x); x < (360 / 16) + first_tile_y; ++x) {

            // move map relative to camera
            m_dst_rect.x = (x * m_size_of_a_tile.getX()) + pCam->getPosition().getX();
            m_dst_rect.y = (y * m_size_of_a_tile.getY()) + pCam->getPosition().getY();

            Tile* t(getTile(layer, x, y));
            if (t) {
                pTextureManager->draw(m_tilesets[layer]->getTextureIndex(), getTile(layer, x, y)->src, m_dst_rect);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an impact on performance using one method over another?

Comment: [Only one way to know for sure](http://quick-bench.com/)

Comment: Please let us know what makes code better. Is the faster code unconditionally better? Then use Nathans advice. Do you need to understand your code easily in 6 months? Use the code which you find easier to read. Want others (colleagues, friends, open source community) to like it better? That is too opinionated a question.

Comment: As it's a loop to render a vector of tiles, it must run as fast as possible.I just wonder if it's better to call a method just one time before the loop (and store the result in a new variable) or to call methods many times inside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically the second version is to be preferred as it does contain the object in the scope where it is being used, not leaking it to different contexts. Performance wise you will need to profile but I'd be surprised if there was any difference at all because a compiler will often notice that the results don't change, at least for simple functions, and do this optimization for you.

For functions that are more complex or potentially dynamic, but you know they will not change their result during the for loop it makes sense to define them before the loop.

Comment: Compilers optimize pretty well these days, it would not surprise me if both would result in the same assembly

Comment: Good to know. As a new user of C++ I did not know of the compiler consider that. I use assembler in another life and for me I thought that is was better to keep a result rather than calculate it many times (on this case within a loop)

Comment: The particular optimization that does this is called loop invariant motion (`-ftree-loop-im` in gcc). It moves expressions that don't change out of the loop to avoid redundant operations.